# how to display lightning lookups when user opens it in lightning experience and display classic lookups when user in classic

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, cti

We have created a softphone using visualforce components. In classic it is fine, but when a user opens lightning experience some places are looking like classic only like lookup pages etc. How we can change that UI as lightning page when user in lightning experience.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Global element `User.UIThemeDisplayed` to identify if you are classic or in LEX and based on that can show different UI.

```
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{! $User.UIThemeDisplayed == 'Theme3' }">
    <apex:outputText value="This is Salesforce Classic."/>
    <apex:outputText value="These are multiple components wrapped by an outputPanel."/>
</apex:outputPanel>
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{! $User.UIThemeDisplayed == 'Theme4d' }">
    <apex:outputText value="Everything is simpler in Lightning Experience."/>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

[Share Visualforce Between Classic and Lightning Experience](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/lex_dev_visualforce/units/lex_dev_visualforce_multipurpose_pages)

Comment: Thanks but We are using remoteAction methods along with javascript and jquery for softphone and dialer. We didn't used these visualforce components much. can you help me in this @Tushar Sharma.

Comment: @ApexCode sure Add these lines in your VF page and you will get different message based on selected UI. And then remove the content of outputpanel and then you need to use different lookup one for classic and one for lightning.

Comment: Hi Tushar can we do like this, if user clicks on contact lookup it has to check the current page url and based on page url it navigates to associate visualforce pages.

Comment: @ApexCode you need to create custom lookup for this.